# powershell get-content with linenumber

Tags: string, powershell

Hi there need some help to add linenumber in get-content output used like that:

```
Get-Content ("\\....”) -tail 1 -wait | %{

    foreach ($data in (,$_ -match "somestring")) {
   ........
    } #end foreach

} #end get-content %
```

already tried with select-object linenumber but without luck. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need to better explain what you are trying to do, at the moment it's hard to understand what you want... Are you trying to get the content of a specific linenumber? Find the line number of a specific string? Add line numbers to a file?

Comment: thx, need to get wholes lines (whole string) from a file matching "error" and in case of match need let's say -10 lines before  a match to + 10 lines after a match. At the end i need 21 lines for each match. My idea was to get the linenumber with an error and then cut -10 +10 surrounding lines.

Comment: `Get-Item .\file.txt |Select-String "error" -Context 10`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You should make that an answer, it's exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: How to put it together right now. What i need:  1. Find and error base on "error" string 2. extract data from row with a match (do some sth with it - i use jira rest api to automate an issue creation. ) 3. Put whole -context 10 into body of jira issue. I was doing it using my code in foreach block. Now tried this one: Get-Content ("path”) -tail 1000 -wait | Select-String "error" -Context 10 | %{
    foreach ($data in ,$_) {
    $bodyjira = $data #this works extracting whole 21 lines
    $summaryjira = Select-String $data -pattern "Getting status" # this is not working

Comment: ok probably solved with select-string -pattern "Getting status" -InputObject $data